# Windows Phone 8.1 Error with SQLite Class

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 and now I need execute select command to obtain row or rows and save these in List.  My function is this:

```
    public async Task<List<string>> execute_SelectCommand(string command)
    {
        //Declaration of variables
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            stringList = await connectionDb.ExecuteScalarAsync<List<string>>(command);
            return stringList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            return stringList = null;
        }

    }
```

But in this code SQLite class give me a error.

[image]

This class can accept values as int, string, double but no List or array. Any idea what can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecuteScalarAsync` command is used to get the **first column from the first row** of the result set, that's why the debugger is telling you that it's not able to convert the result into a `List<string>`, you're probably looking for `ExecuteQuery` instead

Comment: But the Execute query used for sqlite tables as object no?